# How to hide Boost intrusive list hook ?

Tags: c++, boost, intrusive-containers, boost-intrusive

In the following code:

```
using namespace boost::intrusive;

struct Data {
    int i;
private:
    list_member_hook<> list_node;     // How to make this work?
};


using List = list<
    Data,
    member_hook< Data, list_member_hook<>,
    &Data::list_node>      // compiler error here.
>;
```

How can I make `list_node` private?

Comment: Define list inside the Data class as public type, and then use it like `Data::list`

Comment: @VictorGubin Good idea... But maybe something less intrusive? Here https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/IntrusiveList.h says something about "befriend other"...

Comment: @VictorGubin Actually, make this an answer - I'll accept it if found nothing else.